# Dynamically switching between lists to display Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I need to be able to switch between lists to display in vuejs. So something like:

```
  <app-card
        v-for="card in cardsCache[currentCategory]"
        :key="card"
        :affiliateLink="card.affiliateLink"
        :author="card.author"
        :category="card.category"
        :comments="card.comments"
        :description="card.description"
        :downvotes="card.downvotes"
        :id="card.id"
        :imageUrl="card.imageUrl"
        :timeCreated="card.timeCreated"
        :title="card.title"
        :upvotes="card.upvotes"
        @click-card="clickCard"
        @click-upvote="clickUpvote"
        @click-downvote="clickDownvote"
        @click-affiliateLink="clickAffiliateLink"
        @click-comments="clickComments"
        @click-save="clickSave"
      ></app-card>
```

Notice what I'm doing with the vfor, I'm accessing an object with the currentCategory variable which could change at anytime. This sort of works but has issues. When I initially switch category it will render as expected, but if I continue to add to the array for the recently switched to category it will not continue to render to render what's being added to the list. And yes I checked the list is actually having items be added. I've found that any lists added to the cardsCache object as a literal, so: `cardsCache: {"popular": []}` then this issue does not happen for that list. I've also found that if I switch to and from the same list it will suddenly render all the new items added to it. It's like vuejs has trouble watching objects. I would think what I'm trying to do is fairly basic but I haven't been able to find any examples of people doing this.

Below is how I'm adding data to be displayed:

````
      const self = this;
      if (Util.nullOrUndefined(self.cardsCache[category])) {
        self.cardsCache[category] = [];
      }
      if (self.previousCategory != self.currentCategory) {
        Util.scrollToTop();
      }

      if (this.loadingCards === false) {
        if (category == "search") {
          this.cardSearch();
        } else {
          this.loadingCards = true;
          ApiCalls.loadCardsFromCategory(
            this,
            category,
            resp => {
              let cards = resp.data.resp.api_data.cards;
              parseCards(cards).forEach(c => {
                self.cardsCache[category].push(c);
              });

              self.previousCategory = self.currentCategory;
              self.currentCategory = category;
              self.loadingCards = false;
            },
            (error, context) => {
              console.log(error);
              self.loadingCards = false;
            },
            this.userId
          );
        }
      }
    },```

You'll want to pay attention to the line where I say ```self.cardsCache[category].push(c)```
````

Comment: Check out vues dynamic component, you can conditionally render a component with the `is` prop.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look

Comment: I don't think that would solve my problem

Comment: The issue isn't getting vuejs to properly see when currentCategory changes, the issue is getting vuejs to properly watch and render newly added and or modified lists.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve your problem. One of them may be use of [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

```
{
  data() {
    return { 
      currentCategory: 'animals',
      cardsCache: {},
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentCards: function () {
      return this.cardsCache[this.currentCategory];
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

The problem also may be caused by improper use of [`:key` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) in your `v-for` - it should be number or a string, not an object - something like `card.id`.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look into the key, I did try the computed property but it had the same issue.

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything sadly.

Comment: Ya I used card.id as the key, which should be unique. However I suppose various lists being rendered may contain some of the same cards and therefore some of the same ids, but I don't think that would matter.

Comment: So may be the problem is not in your Vue code, but in the way you populate your `cardsCache`

Comment: I mean I can see plenty of data going into the cache when I do a console log and I'm not getting console errors. Do you think this isn't the proper way to render in vue ?

Comment: Maybe add `console.log(self.cardsCache)` in request callback just to make sure that your data is as it should be.

Comment: I'm going to cry haha , I fixed it. After I added stuff to the cache I called self.$forceUpdate() which made vuejs look at the stupid cache which then made render the stuff in the cache. What pain in the A$$

Answer (score 0):

Adding in `self.$forceUpdate()` to the part after I loaded more data into the cache this forced vue to rerender the lists which fixed the problem.

Comment: This isn't really a solution to the underlying problem, you're just papering over the cracks and they'll come back to cause more problems down the line. I suspect the real problem is simply that you're falling foul of one of the reactivity caveats, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats. For the code provided I would guess that `self.cardsCache[category] = []` needs changing to `self.$set(self.cardsCache, category, [])`. That should keep everything reactive and Vue will automatically do the rendering update.